# Recaptcha V2 en varios modales PHP -No funciona

Tags: php, modal, recaptcha

despues de 3 semanas intentando avanzar en la integración de Recaptcha V2 vengo a exponer el caso en este medio quizá alguien puede orientarme para lograr que todos los modales quede protegidos contra el spam que abunda en internet.

**Gracias de antemano:**
En mi proyecto estoy usando Boostrap 5.0.2 y tengo 4 modales que són:
a) Registro
b) Inicio de sesión.
c) Restauración de contraseña.
d) Publicar opinión.

Lo que busco, como lo dije al inicio de este escrito es proteger mi sitio del spam y los auto bots que abundan en internet, para mi mala fortuna no he logrado que todos los modales funcionen correctamente - Y ya no sé como hacer que funcione-

En mi archivo index.php tengo el siguiente código (me voy a limitar a colocar los modales y el ajax con el que manejo las solititudes)

```js
// Función para manejar el formulario de inicio de sesión con Ajax
            $("#login-form").submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                recaptchaResponse = grecaptcha.getResponse();
                console.log(recaptchaResponse);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "login.php",
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(response) {
                        if (response.status === "success") {
                            Swal.fire({
                                icon: 'success',
                                title: '¡Éxito!',
                                text: response.message,
                            }).then(() => {
                                window.location.reload(); // Aquí redirecciona o realiza otras acciones necesarias
                            });
                        } else {
                            Swal.fire({
                                icon: 'error',
                                title: 'Error',
                                text: response.message,
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        Swal.fire({
                            icon: 'error',
                            title: 'Error',
                            text: 'Hubo un problema al procesar la solicitud.',
                        });
                    },
                });
            });

            // Función para manejar el formulario de registro con Ajax
            $("#register-form").submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "register.php",
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        if (response.status === "success") {
                            Swal.fire({
                                icon: 'success',
                                title: '¡Registro exitoso!',
                                text: response.message,
                            }).then(() => {
                                // Aquí redirecciona o realiza otras acciones necesarias
                            });
                        } else {
                            Swal.fire({
                                icon: 'error',
                                title: 'Error',
                                text: response.message,
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
                        Swal.fire({
                            icon: 'error',
                            title: 'Error',
                            text: ' Detalles: ' + errorThrown,
                        });
                    },

                });
            });


        });
        
        
        function AddReview() {

            var nameAdd = $('#user_name').val();
            var reviewAdd = $('#user_review').val();
            var emailAdd = $('#user_email').val();
            var ratingAdd = rating_data;
            var avatarAdd = gravatar_image_url;
            var recaptchaResponseReady = grecaptcha.getResponse();
            var errors = [];

            if (nameAdd === '') {
                errors.push('Please Set an User Name');
            }

            if (reviewAdd === '') {
                errors.push('Please write your review');
            }

            if (emailAdd === '' || !isValidEmail(emailAdd)) {
                errors.push('Please write a valid email');
            }

            if (ratingAdd === 0) {
                errors.push('Please set a score');
            }

            if (errors.length > 0) {
                // Si hay errores, muestra una sola alerta con todos los errores
                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: 'Oops...',
                    html: errors.join('<br>')
                });
            } else {

                $.ajax({
                    url: "submit_rating.php",
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {

                        nameSend: nameAdd,
                        reviewSend: reviewAdd,
                        emailSend: emailAdd,
                        avatarSend: avatarAdd,
                        ratingSend: ratingAdd,
                        recaptchaResponseReady: recaptchaResponseReady
                    },
                    success: function(data, status) {
                        console.log(recaptchaResponseReady);
                        if (data === 'success') {
                            $('#reviewModal').modal('hide');
                            displayData();
                            displayRating();
                            clearModal();
                        } else {
                            $('#recaptchaError').text('Por favor, completa el reCAPTCHA.').show();
                            $('.g-recaptcha').css('border', '2px solid red');
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css">
   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10/dist/sweetalert2.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!--review modal-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="reviewModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="reviewModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="reviewModalLabel">Escribe tu opinión sobre <strong><?php echo strtoupper($page_name); ?></strong></h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <img id="avatar" src="https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/4960b5c8e92e02c3cc04280e7b0b259a?s=80" />
                    <h4 class="text-center mt-2 mb-4">
                        <i class="fas fa-star star-light submit_star mr-1" id="submit_star_1" data-rating="1"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star star-light submit_star mr-1" id="submit_star_2" data-rating="2"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star star-light submit_star mr-1" id="submit_star_3" data-rating="3"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star star-light submit_star mr-1" id="submit_star_4" data-rating="4"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star star-light submit_star mr-1" id="submit_star_5" data-rating="5"></i>
                    </h4>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Name" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{8,}" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="user_email" id="user_email" class="form-control" placeholder="user@domain.com" required />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="lead emoji-picker-container" style="height: 100px;text-align: left;">
                            <textarea name="user_review" id="user_review" class="form-control" placeholder="Type Review Here" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{8,}" data-emojiable="true" required style="height: 100px;"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="g-recaptcha" style="width: 305px; height: 80px;" data-sitekey="<?php echo $siteKey; ?>"></div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response" id="recaptcha_response">

                    <br>
                    <div id="recaptchaError" style="color: red;"></div>
                    <div class="form-group text-center mt-4">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="AddReview();">Opinar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- Modal Login registro y reset password -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="loginModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="loginModalLabel">Iniciar sesión / Registrarse</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <!-- Pestañas para seleccionar entre Iniciar sesión y Registrarse -->
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" id="login-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#login-content">Iniciar sesión</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" id="register-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#register-content">Registrarse</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Contenido de inicio de sesión y registro -->
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <!-- Contenido de inicio de sesión -->
                        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="login-content">
                            <form id="login-form">
                                <!-- Campos de inicio de sesión -->
                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login-username-email" name="login-username-email" placeholder="Usuario o Correo Electrónico" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="login-password" name="login-password" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <!-- Integración de reCAPTCHA v2 -->
                                    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo $siteKey ?>"></div>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Iniciar sesión</button>

                                <div class="mt-3">
                                    <!-- Enlace "¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?" -->
                                    <a href="#" id="forgot-password-link">¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?</a>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <div class="hr-container">
                                    <div class="hr-line"></div>
                                    <div class="hr-line-right"></div>
                                    <div class="hr-text">O continua con:</div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Proveedores de servicio -->
                                <ul class="list-inline">
                                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-discord"></i></a></li>
                                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-google"></i></a></li>
                                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-vk"></i></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Contenido de registro -->
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="register-content" class="d-none">
                            <form id="register-form">
                                <!-- Campos de registro -->
                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="register-username" name="register-username" placeholder="Nombre de Usuario" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="register-email" name="register-email" placeholder="Correo Electrónico" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="register-password" name="register-password" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
                                    <!-- Agregar aquí lógica de validación para contraseñas seguras -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <!-- Integración de reCAPTCHA v2 -->
                                    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo $siteKey ?>"></div>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Registrarse</button>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="my-3">
                                    <!-- Enlace "¿Ya tienes una cuenta?" -->
                                    <a href="#login-content" id="already-have-account-link">¿Ya tienes una cuenta?</a>
                                </div>

                            </form>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Contenido de restaurar contraseña -->
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="forgot-password-content" class="d-none">
                            <form id="forgot-password-form">
                                <div class="my-3">
                                    <p>Ingresa tu correo electrónico y te enviaremos un enlace para restablecer tu contraseña.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="mb-3">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="forgot-password-email" name="forgot-password-email" placeholder="Correo Electrónico" required>
                                </div>
                                 <!-- Integración de reCAPTCHA v2 -->
                                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo $siteKey ?>"></div>
                                <br>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Restablecer Contraseña</button>
                                <div class="mt-3">
                                    <div class="hr-container">
                                        <div class="hr-line"></div>
                                        <div class="hr-line-right"></div>
                                        <div class="hr-text">O también puedes</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Enlace "Iniciar sesión" -->
                                    <a href="#" id="back-to-login-link">Iniciar sesión</a>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <!-- Enlaces a Términos y Condiciones y Política de Privacidad -->
                    <a href="#">Términos y Condiciones</a> | <a href="#">Política de Privacidad</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>





<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Ya completo poco mas de 3 semanas en esto y no sé como hacer que funcione, en este codigo AJAX que he suministrado no estoy obteniendo el valor del recaptcharesponse entonces el tema es que si trato de imprimir en consola el resultado del captcha `console.log(recaptchaResponse);` el valor que recibo en la consola es vacio por lo tanto los archivos de validacion como login.php, submit_rating.php no reciben la respuesta y el script se detiene. (al menos esa parte si funciona :)..)

**¿QUÉ HE INTENTADO?**

1. He intentado renderizar cada recaptcha asignando un id a cada div contenedor de g-recapctha. ( No funcionó)
2. He intentado rein iciar la variale recaptchaResponse. (No ha funcionado)
3. He asignado un id a cada boton y con ello0 usando una funcion cick para obtener el valor del recapctha (no ha funcinado)

```js
`$('#id_del boton').click(function() {
var recaptchaResponse = grecaptcha.getResponse();
            console.log(recaptchaResponse);

});`
```

4. Incluso he colocado los modales en otro archivo junto con el js (tampoco funcionó)
5. Usé chatGPT tampoco funcionaron sus sugerencias.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que te falta `"` en tu script que hace la comunicación con `api.js` de Google.

Intenta corregirlo de:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js></script>
```

a

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
```

Igualmente, te recomiendo basarte en la [documentación del reCAPTCHA](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display?hl=es-419) donde prácticamente te dan los scripts, cómo colocarlos, ejemplos, etc. y así evitarás otros errores que pudieran pasar desapercibidos.

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos.